# Discord.py dm command

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  id = member.id
  for a in range(5):
    await bot.send_message(id, "")
```

ive done this my error is :

**raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'message'**

Comment: Kindly improve your question heading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `user = await bot.fetch_user(id)` and then do `await user.send("Hello")`.

```py
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  id = member.id
  user = await bot.fetch_user(id)
  for a in range(5):
    await user.send("Hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the important part of your error, and it basically shows already what it is about; The `bot` has no attribute of `message`, in which it doesn't and should be `member.send` in your case. You also don't need to get the id of the member.

```
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'message'
```

By re-writing your command, here are those errors fixed

```py
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  for a in range(5):
    await member.send("text")
```

You can also add more specific detail to the command, in this example if you don't include   a member it won't cause an error, or if the member was not reachable, it would handle the error.

```py
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
  if member == None:
    await ctx.send('Mention a member')
    return
  try:
    for a in range(5):
      await member.send("text")

  except commands.CommandInvokeError:
      await ctx.send("Couldn't send message to user")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `member.send` instead of `bot.send_message`.